# How can I store a variable as an attribute in my class so it can be used in multiple methods?

Tags: python, json, pandas, variables

I have code like this.

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd

class AcousticResponse():

    def open_file(self): 
        """
        This function is to load the JSON file which is the values that will be used when 
        making measurements
        """
        filetypes = [("Json File", "*.json")] 
        filenames = fd.askopenfilename(title="Open File", filetypes=filetypes)
        self.df = pd.read_json(filenames)
        
    def SignalPath(self):
        APx = APx500_Application()
        APx.Visible = True
        APx.SignalPathSetup.OutputConnector.Type = OutputConnectorType.AnalogBalanced
        APx.SignalPathSetup.InputConnector.Type = InputConnectorType.AnalogBalanced
        APx.SignalPathSetup.Measure = MeasurandType.Acoustic
        input1 = APx.SignalPathSetup.InputSettings(APxInputSelection.Input1)
        input1.Channels[0].Name = "Mic"
        input1.Channels[0].Sensitivity.Value = float(self.df["sensitivity_value_mic"][0])
```

if I run the code above, the error

```
input1.Channels[0].Sensitivity.Value = float(self.df["sensitivity_value_mic"][0])
AttributeError: 'AcousticResponse' object has no attribute 'df'
```

appears. I need the df variable to be used in multiple methods. How can the df variable be stored as an attribute so it can be used in other methods?

I want all the input values loaded from the json file to run the measurements to work in that code. `open_file` will load the json file via button which is created from a separate `.py` file. Then after loading the json file then there is another button to run the `SignalPath` method.

Comment: Are you calling the functions on different instances of `AcousticResponse`?

Comment: The code in your example is not how classes are defined in Python. In fact it looks much more like a function with sub-functions. What you want is to define a `__init__` method, that takes `self` and `filenames` as arguuments, and then defnes `self.df`. Also as already commented, you need to create a new instance of your class first.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling a different function than AcousticResponse

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Classes are not a way of grouping functions together, but rather to describe an object and its attributes. You can set attributes using the __init__() method and defining attributes .

Comment: Please post a [mre] that shows how you're creating the class instancek and calling the methods.'

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you will need to call the function "*open_file*" before instantiating or creating the *self.df* variable. Then only you can access the df attribute. However, there is a way (the proper way to do that). You need to initialize the attributes in the constructor function.

A constructor is a function that gets automatically called when you try to create an instance of the class. Read more about constructor functions [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)). In **python**, constructors can be implemented like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__init__-in-python/)

A solution to your problem would be-

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd

class AcousticResponse():

    def __init__(self): 
        """
        This function is to load the JSON file which is the values that will be used when 
        making measurements
        """
        filetypes = [("Json File", "*.json")] 
        filenames = fd.askopenfilename(title="Open File", filetypes=filetypes)
        self.df = pd.read_json(filenames)
        
    def SignalPath(self):
        APx = APx500_Application()
        APx.Visible = True
        APx.SignalPathSetup.OutputConnector.Type = OutputConnectorType.AnalogBalanced
        APx.SignalPathSetup.InputConnector.Type = InputConnectorType.AnalogBalanced
        APx.SignalPathSetup.Measure = MeasurandType.Acoustic
        input1 = APx.SignalPathSetup.InputSettings(APxInputSelection.Input1)
        input1.Channels[0].Name = "Mic"
        input1.Channels[0].Sensitivity.Value = float(self.df["sensitivity_value_mic"][0])
```

OR, if you want to open the files through your own defined function, you can try-

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd

class AcousticResponse():

    def __init__(self):
        self.open_file()

    def open_file(self): 
        """
        This function is to load the JSON file which is the values that will be used when 
        making measurements
        """
        filetypes = [("Json File", "*.json")] 
        filenames = fd.askopenfilename(title="Open File", filetypes=filetypes)
        self.df = pd.read_json(filenames)
        
    def SignalPath(self):
        APx = APx500_Application()
        APx.Visible = True
        APx.SignalPathSetup.OutputConnector.Type = OutputConnectorType.AnalogBalanced
        APx.SignalPathSetup.InputConnector.Type = InputConnectorType.AnalogBalanced
        APx.SignalPathSetup.Measure = MeasurandType.Acoustic
        input1 = APx.SignalPathSetup.InputSettings(APxInputSelection.Input1)
        input1.Channels[0].Name = "Mic"
        input1.Channels[0].Sensitivity.Value = float(self.df["sensitivity_value_mic"][0])
```

I would also recommend checking out the [function annotations](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/function-annotations-in-python) and [arrow notations](https://medium.com/@thomas_k_r/whats-this-weird-arrow-notation-in-python-53d9e293113).

Comment: Both steps did not work

Comment: What's the error that your are facing, you might need to provide more code for a better understanding.